# How to quickly prune large tables?

Tags: mysql, database, pruning

I currently have a MySQL table of about 20 million rows, and I need to prune it. I'd like to remove every row whose `updateTime` (timestamp of insertion) was more than one month ago. I have not personally performed any alterations of the table's order, so the data should be in the order in which it was inserted, and there is a `UNIQUE` key on two fields, `id` and `updateTime`. How would I go about doing this in a short amount of time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How much down time can you incur? How big are the rows? How many are you deleting?

Simply put, deleting rows is one of the most expensive things you can do to a table. It's just a horrible thing overall.

If you don't have to do it, and you have the disk space for it, and your queries aren't affected by the table size (well indexed queries typically ignore table size), then you may just leave well enough alone.

If you have the opportunity and can take the table offline (and you're removing a good percentage of the table), then your best bet would be to copy the rows you want to keep to a new table, drop the old one, rename the new one to the old name, and THEN recreate your indexes.

Otherwise, you're pretty much stuck with good 'ol delete.

Answer (score 13):

There are two ways to remove a large number of rows. First there is the obvious way:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE updateTime < NOW() - interval 1 month;
```

The second (slightly more complicated) way is to create a new table and copy the data that you want to keep, truncate your old table, then copy the rows back.

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE updateTime >= NOW() - interval 1 month;

TRUNCATE table1;

INSERT INTO table1
SELECT * FROM table2;
```

Using `TRUNCATE` is much faster than a `DELETE` with a `WHERE` clause when you have a large number of rows to delete and a relatively small number that you wish to keep.

Comment: I tried it with a table that had 3.7 million rows. I had to delete 200k rows. The TRUNCATE way was faster. (I got tired of waiting for traditional DELETE after about 10 minutes and the other way took around 3 minutes). I used a TEMPORARY table

Comment: that's good stuff! great way to cut down the time of my backup+restore

Answer (score 0):

Spliting the deletes with limit might speed up the process;

I had to delete 10M rows and i issued the command. It never responded for hours.

I killed the query ( which took couple of hours)

then Split the deletes.

```
DELETE from table where id > XXXX limit 10000;
DELETE from table where id > XXXX limit 10000;
DELETE from table where id > XXXX limit 10000;
DELETE from table where id > XXXX limit 10000;
```

Then i duplicated this statement in a file and used the command.

```
mysql> source /tmp/delete.sql
```

This was much faster.

You can also try to use tools like pt-tools. and pt-archiver.

Answer (score 0):

Actually even if you can't take the table offline for long, you can still use the 'rename table' technique to get rid of old data.

Stop processes writting to table.

```
rename table tableName to tmpTableName;
create table tableName like tmpTableName;
set @currentId=(select max(id) from tmpTableName);
set @currentId=@currentId+1;
set @indexQuery = CONCAT("alter table test auto_increment = ", @currentId);
prepare stmt from @indexQuery;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Start processes writting to table.

```
insert into tableName
select * from tmpTableName;
drop table;
```

New inserts to tableName will begin at the correct index;  The old data will be inserted in correct indexes.